# How should I reapply for a UK visa after being rejected? Original trip was for a PLAB exam

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens

I'm a Pakistani citizen and a doctor. I applied a visa for plab and got refused in May 2016. Reasons were as follows,

> 1. You stated that you are attending a plab 2 exam on 5th july 2016. However, you are planning to stay for 30 days. You state the reason for this is to prepare under proper guidance from friends of similar field. I'm not satisfied that you accurately presented your intentions.
> 2. You state that you are a doctor with an income of 31020PKR per month and provided a employment letter to demonstrate this. The letter from your employer does not show that they are aware of your trip and duration. This undermines the credibility of your application to the extent that I'm not satisfied that your are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor.
> 3. You state that your father has given you PKR 500,000 for the trip. You state that this is from the sale of property. You have provided an affidavit which details the sale of property. However, this affidavit and the other documents do not demonstrate the source of funds provided by your father. Therefore, I'm not satisfied that you are a genuine visitor.

This was refused on 17th May, 2016.

I can tackle the first two points by decreasing my duration of trip to 6 days and getting an other employment letter from my employer with my job details , rank, salary, duration, leaves details and purpose of visit to UK.  I think that would satisfy ECO. Am I right?

Second question is with point three. My previous visa was sponsored by my father. He gave me 500,000PKR which is still in my account. I will provide with property transfer papers now.(initially I gave an affidavit of agreement to sell that has now completed) and will explain that 500,000 transaction. Now I m employed at 82,000PKR per month from May 18th, 2016. I had deposited three salaries in my account and all of them were cash deposits as I am paid in cash and I've got salary slips verifying the dates on which amount was deposited in my account. So, I want to apply visa this time as self sponsored.

Is it a reasonable way to apply or not? Please suggest something if its not proper.
In this case what documents do I need to provide? 
Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: Given you're taking a PLAB I would suggest shorten the duration.  Taking an exam throws all sorts of red flags on your visitor status.

Comment: The next time, based on other PLAB-related question, may include the question, why aren't you taking it locally/in a closer location?

Comment: I received reply on 21st may and decision was made on 17. I came to know on 21st that I have been refused. I didn't know before it. @pnuts

Comment: Can someone please answer my actual question?

Comment: @phoog You're correct. The second part is only given in the UK.